# Frequency component not filtered properly

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals

Are frequency components other than wanted signal present in the output? If yes then why does it not disturb the original signal? I think all practical filter responses are not ideal, so all frequency components present at the antenna are still, though small amplitude, present at the output of the filter. Why does it not disturb the original signal?

Comment: Do you think you can clarify your question by describing the system you are dealing with? What signal? In which output? What is the filter supposed to filter? What antenna? Is this a communications system? What is the original and the "wanted" signal?

Answer (score 0):

In engineering, there is always a good enough attenuation for all practical purposes. The output of the filter might still have some unwanted components but if they are 30 dB below the signal of interest (1000 times weaker), they are practically of no consequence. But still, yes, the unwanted signal is still there corrupting our wanted signal ever so slightly.

So an engineer is satisfied with a certain amount of attenuation and can live with those unwanted components still being present in the output. The amount of attenuation needed depends on the application.

You can set up a small experiment using Matlab. Use two sine waves with different frequencies and try to filter the higher frequency one with many different low pass filters with different attenuations at the higher frequency. Observe or visually inspect the amount of distortion to the pure sine wave in the filter output. You will see that depending on the attenuation it will look good enough (close enough to a pure sine wave) even though it has a very small unwanted component.

Comment: Thank you so much i will try to understand it